# MySQL return all but I want to get only like some results

Tags: mysql

I want get rows from MySQL where column `nazwa` contains words `zero` and `no` but I get all results.

MySQL code:

```
SELECT *, IF (nazwa LIKE '%Zero%', 1, 0)+IF (nazwa LIKE '%no%', 1, 0) AS nazwa FROM odc_ListaAnime WHERE statuts='zaakceptowane' HAVING nazwa > 0 ORDER BY id DESC;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two columns named `nazwa` and that confuses the compiler.  Name the result something else, if you want to use the MySQL extension of including the alias in the `having` clause:

```
SELECT *,
       IF(nazwa LIKE '%Zero%', 1, 0) + IF(nazwa LIKE '%no%', 1, 0) AS NumNazwa
FROM odc_ListaAnime
WHERE statuts = 'zaakceptowane'
HAVING Numnazwa > 0
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

However, why not just write:

```
SELECT *,
       IF(nazwa LIKE '%Zero%', 1, 0) + IF(nazwa LIKE '%no%', 1, 0) AS NumNazwa
FROM odc_ListaAnime
WHERE statuts = 'zaakceptowane' AND
      (nazwa LIKE '%Zero%', 1, 0 OR nazwa LIKE '%no%', 1, 0)
ORDER BY id DESC;
```

You can remove the expression from the `SELECT` if you don't really need it.

Comment: because this code is generated by php code and numbers of words are different